# Loading Glide image

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am working on developing an app to play songs, I use Glide to get the image of the song and display it in the ListView,
**the first problem**
when I scrolling in my ListView the application becomes slow, and I have **another problem** which is when I scrolling Up the Glide load the images that have already been loaded  Is there a way to fix these problems?

**here is my code to get the image of songs**

```
`

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAdapter
extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private static ArrayList<ListItemFromPhone> newList = new ArrayList<>();
ListAdapter(){}
ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItemFromPhone> list) {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.context = context;
    newList = list;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return newList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return newList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view,null);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            byte [] imgArtist = getImg(newList.get(position).data);
            if (imgArtist != null){
                Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                        .load(imgArtist)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.music_img)
                        .into(imageView);
            }
            else imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_img);
    textView.setText(newList.get(position).name);

    return view;
}
private byte[] getImg(String path){
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(path);
    byte[] img = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
    retriever.release();
    return img;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem you must use `RecyclerView`. There are a lot of tutorials on youtube on how to implement it.

Comment: I got the same problem when using RecyclerView